# Appending current Share Price to Historic Daily Share Price on Google Sheet GOOGLEFINANCE Function Sparkline

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-sheets-sparkline

I have a sparkline for the daily price for the last 30 days for a share in google sheets using the following formula (F1):

F1 =SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",Today()-30,Today()))

I can also get the current share price using a second formula (F2):

F2 =GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price")

I was just wondering if there is a way to append this value (F2 output) onto the end of the sparkline returned from F1, to get a hybrid sparkline with the current SP shown.

**Note:** I could put the output of the table of historic data provided in F1 (just this bit: GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",Today()-30,Today()) into another sheet, and then append the current SP on the bottom of the output... but I wanted to be able to vary the number of historic days and the share in question, and have this for a large number of shares, so a formula solution would be preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and finally found someone who had the solution which I pasted in the below link.

[Link to how to append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521446/how-to-append-todays-price-in-historical-googlefinance-prices-to-generate-spark)

Comment: Hi. Links are not ok, as they change. You should post the full answer here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/145937)